# testing keydown events in Jasmine with specific keyCode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I am writing tests for an AngularJS directive which fires events of a `<textarea>` when certain keys are pressed. It all works fine per my manual testing. I want to be good and have a full unit-test suite too, but I have run into a problem I can't solve on my own:

I want to send a specific `keyCode` in my `triggerHandler()` call in my test, but I can't find a way to specify the key **that actually works**. I am aware of a *lot* of questions and answers on the topic of building and sending events with specific data, but none of them work on my setup:

### My setup

- Karma test runner
- PhantomJS browser running the tests (but also tried Firefox and Chrome without success)
- I'm not using jQuery and I'm hoping there is a regular JS solution. There must be!

### Test code

```
var event = document.createEvent("Events");
event.initEvent("keydown", true, true);
event.keyCode = 40; // in debugging the test in Firefox, the event object can be seen to have no "keyCode" property even after this step
textarea.triggerHandler(event); // my keydown handler does not fire
```

The strange thing is, I can type the first 3 lines into the console in Chrome and see that the event is being created *with* the `keyCode` property set to 40.
 So it seems like it should work.

Also, when I call the last line like this `textarea.triggerHandler("keydown");` it works and the event handler is triggered. However, there is no `keyCode` to work with, so it is pointless.

I suspect it may be something to do with the nature of the test running against a DOM that is different to a regular page running in the browser. But I can't figure it out!

Comment: This is what you apparently need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832059/definitive-way-to-trigger-keypress-events-with-jquery

Comment: Hi, that discussion is specifically about jQuery, which I'm not using. I'm hoping I don't need to include jQuery in my unit tests just for this.

Comment: I think I've already answered this for pure JS, but apparently that question was deleted. You should be able to find more info on MDN.

Comment: In other [thread][1] I've added answer and described how to test keydown.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001169/how-do-i-trigger-a-keyup-keydown-event-in-an-angularjs-unit-test/28146595#28146595

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've used the following solution to test it and having it working in Chrome, FF, PhantomJS and IE9+ based on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455626/keydown-simulation-in-chrome-fires-normally-but-not-the-correct-key/12522769#12522769).
It doesn't work in Safari - tried millions of other solution without any success...

```
function jsKeydown(code){
  var oEvent = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');

  // Chromium Hack: filter this otherwise Safari will complain
  if( navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1 ){
    Object.defineProperty(oEvent, 'keyCode', {
      get : function() {
        return this.keyCodeVal;
      }
    });     
    Object.defineProperty(oEvent, 'which', {
      get : function() {
        return this.keyCodeVal;
      }
    });
  }

  if (oEvent.initKeyboardEvent) {
    oEvent.initKeyboardEvent("keydown", true, true, document.defaultView, false, false, false, false, code, code);
  } else {
    oEvent.initKeyEvent("keydown", true, true, document.defaultView, false, false, false, false, code, 0);
  }

  oEvent.keyCodeVal = code;

  if (oEvent.keyCode !== code) {
    console.log("keyCode mismatch " + oEvent.keyCode + "(" + oEvent.which + ") -> "+ code);
  }

  document.getElementById("idToUseHere").dispatchEvent(oEvent);
}

// press DEL key
jsKeydown(46);
```

Hope it helps

### Update

Today I've found and tested this solution which is offers a much wider coverage of browsers (enabling the legacy support):

https://gist.github.com/termi/4654819

All the credit goes to the author of this GIST.
The code does support Safari, PhantomJS and IE9 - tested for the first 2.

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot! I modified it slightly to return the event object, which I then put inside the Angular `element.triggerHandler()` method, and it works well. I had given up on this one; I'm now busy finishing off my test suite!

Comment: @MarcoCI you are using PhantomJS? I keep getting an error that the keyCode is mismatched.

Comment: Same here. Some sort this problem ?

Comment: Just updated with a better solution that covers Safari and PhantomJS.

Comment: The linked code doesn't work in PhantomJS 1.9.8. `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'Function.prototype.call.bind(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty)')`

Comment: @helion3 bind is not available in phantom but you can add this polyfill to your dev dependencies to avoid that error: https://github.com/kdimatteo/bind-polyfill

Comment: This doesn't work in PhantomJS 1.9.8, keyCode always are 0

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @MarcoL answer, I'd like to point out for future readers who might stumble on this question, that the methods `initKeyboardEvent` and `initKeyEvent` are deprecated methods, and should no longer be used. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/initKeyboardEvent)  and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/initKeyEvent).

Instead as the MDN docs suggested, events should be created via their respective constructor.