# Test keydown event in AngularJS with Jasmine and PhantomJS

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

I tried to implement solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23700583/2677738) with this function, but this doesn't work, everytime I have `oEvent.keyCode = 0`

In unit tests keydown event are triggered, but I can't test if specific key are pressed.

**SOLUTION:**
This worked for me with PhantomJS 1.9.8

```
function simulateKeydownEvent(element, keyCode) {
    var event = document.createEvent("Events");
    event.initEvent("keydown", true, true);
    event.keyCode = keyCode;
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: did you see this documentation page http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/ ?
I suggest you to use the jQlight api to trigger a new custom event.

Comment: I found solution without jQuery, look at SOLUTION from question :)

Comment: My comment was about jqlite that is a lightweight version of jQuery built-in on AngularJS...

Comment: I know, but I tried and it doest'n work, keycode also was zero

Comment: Thank you this is worked for me. I have been looking for a solution whole morning.