# Test in Karma/Jasmine getModifierState

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

How to test this method (angular):

```
 public detectCapslock(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
        let capsOn: boolean = event.getModifierState && event.getModifierState("CapsLock");
        if (capsOn) {
            this.capsOn = "Caps Lock on";
        } else {
            this.capsOn = "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Put a own created keyboard event in it and check the result.

Comment: @Swoox how to create `KeyboardEvent` in Karma?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41135875/unable-to-simulate-keypress-event-in-angular-2-unit-test-jasmine

Answer (score 0):

We can do something like this:

```
// Assemble
const event = new KeyboardEvent('keyup', {
  key: 'CapsLock',
  code: 'CapsLock',
  modifierCapsLock: true,
});

// Act
document.dispatchEvent(event);

// Assert
expect(component.capsOn).toEqual('Caps Lock on');
```

or in your case:

```
// Assemble
const event = new KeyboardEvent('keyup', {
  key: 'CapsLock',
  code: 'CapsLock',
  modifierCapsLock: true,
});

// Act
compoent.detectCapslock(event);

// Assert
expect(component.capsOn).toEqual('Caps Lock on');
```